# Where Clause in LINQ with IN operator

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ function that returns a summary table.

```
 private DataTable CreateSummaryFocusOfEffortData()
    {
        var result = ReportData.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(row => new
                                {
                                    Value = row.Field<string>("Value"),
                                    Description = row.Field<string>("Description")

                                })
            .Select(g =>
                        {
                            var row = g.First();
                            row.SetField("Hours", g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Hours")));

                            return row;
                        });

      return result.CopyToDataTable();
    }
```

Now I want to add a WHERE clause to this function so that it only sums up rows for fields that are there in a list. Something like the IN operator in sql. For example : Lets say I have a list with values (1,2,3) and I want to base by where clause with values that are there in list.

Comment: What is with the negative score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example of how you could try it:

```
private DataTable CreateSummaryFocusOfEffortData(List<int> yourList)
{
    var result = ReportData.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(row => new
                            {
                                Value = row.Field<string>("Value"),
                                Description = row.Field<string>("Description")

                            })
        .Select(g =>
                    {
                        var row = g.First();
                        row.SetField("Hours", 
                                     g.Where(r=>yourList.Contains(r.Field<int>("Id")))
                                      .Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Hours")));

                        return row;
                    });

  return result.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.Works like a charm. Much appreciated.